# java set id after query

Tags: java, mysql, swing

I have a method that makes an insert and return an integer (the id of the inserted row), i want to  create a panel with this ID but the problem is that the ID is null when i create the panel.

This is the code..

```
               Integer id=null;
               try {
                    id = db.insertProject(textField.getText(),textField_1.getText(),(String)comboBox.getSelectedItem());
                    MyPanel p1 = new MyPanel(id,textField.getText(),textField_1.getText(),"laptop.png");

                    pan5.revalidate();
                    pan5.repaint();
                    pan5.add(p1,new BoxLayout(p1, BoxLayout.X_AXIS));

                } catch (SQLException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
```

And this is the method insertProject

```
public Integer insertProject(String nome,String desc,String cat) throws SQLException{
Integer id = null;
Date date = new Date(System.currentTimeMillis());
SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");
String s = formatter.format(date);

String sql = "INSERT INTO progetto (name,descrizione,categoria,stato,data) VALUES ('"+nome+"','"+desc+"','"+cat+"',1,'"+s+"')";


try {
    stmt = conn.createStatement();
    stmt.executeUpdate(sql);

    try (ResultSet generatedKeys = stmt.getGeneratedKeys()) {
        if (generatedKeys.next()) {
            id = generatedKeys.getInt(1);
        }else {
            throw new SQLException("Creating project failed, no ID obtained.");
        }
    }
} catch (SQLException e) {
    //
}   
stmt.close();
return id;
}
```

Any suggestion?

Answer (score 1):

You need to specify that you want the query to return the auto generated keys, try this:

```
stmt.executeUpdate(sql, Statement.RETURN_GENERATED_KEYS);
```